# Encrypt Decrypt my own key not generated java

Tags: java, key, encryption

I am new to cryptography, so I have a question:

How can I create my own key (let`s say like a string "1234"). Because I need to encrypt a string with a key (defined by me), save the encrypted string in a database and when I want to use it, take it from the database and decrypt it with the key known by me.

I have this code :

```
   import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
   import java.security.*;
   import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
   import javax.crypto.Cipher;
   import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
   import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
   import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
   import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;

      public class LocalEncrypter {

    private static String algorithm = "PBEWithMD5AndDES";
   //private static Key key = null;
    private static Cipher cipher = null;
    private static SecretKey key;

    private static void setUp() throws Exception {
        ///key = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        String pass1 = "thisIsTheSecretKeyProvidedByMe";
        byte[] pass = pass1.getBytes(); 
        SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(pass));
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
       throws Exception {
        setUp();

        byte[] encryptionBytes = null;
        String input = "1234";
        System.out.println("Entered: " + input);
        encryptionBytes = encrypt(input);
        System.out.println(
          "Recovered: " + decrypt(encryptionBytes));
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(String input)
        throws InvalidKeyException, 
               BadPaddingException,
               IllegalBlockSizeException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes();
        return cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
    }

    private static String decrypt(byte[] encryptionBytes)
        throws InvalidKeyException, 
               BadPaddingException,
               IllegalBlockSizeException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] recoveredBytes = 
          cipher.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
        String recovered = 
          new String(recoveredBytes);
        return recovered;
      }
```

}

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Invalid key spec
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKeyFactory.engineGenerateSecret(PBEKeyFactory.java:114)
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:335)
at LocalEncrypter.setUp(LocalEncrypter.java:22)
at LocalEncrypter.main(LocalEncrypter.java:28)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A KeyGenerator generates random keys. Since you know the secret key, what you need is a [SecretKeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html). Get an instance for your algorithm (DESede), and then call its generateSecret méthode with an instance of [DESedeKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/DESedeKeySpec.html) as argument:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(someByteArrayContainingAtLeast24Bytes));
```

Here is a complete example that works. As I said, DESedeKeySpec must be used with the DESede algorithm. Using a DESede key with PBEWithMD5AndDES makes no sense.

```
public class EncryptionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = "1234567890azertyuiopqsdf".getBytes("ASCII");
        DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        byte[] text = "Hello world".getBytes("ASCII");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text);

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        System.out.println(new String(decrypted, "ASCII"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don`t know how to use it , i tried SecretKeyFactory and many variants but with no success

Comment: See my edit, then. You should have shown us what you tried in your question, and told us what didn't work.

Comment: i converted a string in a bye[] , used secretkeyfactory , but now it gives me the error :  No installed provider supports this key: (null) , ------                                                          SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
         String pass1 = "123456789132456789123456789";
         byte[] pass = pass1.getBytes(); 
         SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(pass));

Comment: DESede is supported natively by the JRE: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory. Please edit your question with the code, the exception stack trace, and the potentially installed providers.

Comment: i have changed this :private static String algorithm = "PBEWithMD5AndDES"; and now i get the error : Invalid Key Spec

Comment: What should i do now ? I can`t get it to work and it is very important for me.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, the exception stack trace, and the potentially installed providers.

Comment: Sigh. I told you that a DESedeKeySpec had to be used with the DESede algorithm. You don't use your car key to open your house, do you? See my answer. I gave you a complete example that works.

Comment: How can i print out the encrypted string because i need to save it in a database; Sorry for the stupid questions but i`m new to this

Comment: Save it as bnary in database, or use Base64 (apache commons codec has an implementation) to transform the byte array into an printable String.

Comment: But when i try to print it out , it gives me [B.... and that is diferent every time ,.. i use System.out.println(encrypted);

Comment: That's the type (byte[] = [B) followed by the hash code of the array. Use java.util.Arrays.toString(encrypted). Google is your friend: this question comes every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution after combining from here and there. The encrypted result will be formatted as Base64 String for safe saving as xml file.

```
package cmdCrypto;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class CmdCrypto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            final String strPassPhrase = "123456789012345678901234"; //min 24 chars

            String param = "No body can see me";
        System.out.println("Text : " + param);

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
            SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(strPassPhrase.getBytes()));
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            String str = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cipher.doFinal(param.getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Text Encryted : " + str);

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        String str2 = new String(cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str)));
        System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + str2);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```